# Android sdk manager I don't have Android Support Library

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-support-library

I do a Android training and I have to use Eclipse. I created a new project and I get the error

android.support cannot resolved.

I look for the android-support-*.jar.

This is my SDK manager

[image]

I don't have Android Support Library package in my SDK Manager. How can I install the package "Android Support Library" ?

Comment: Switch to Android Studio first

Comment: It's mandatory to use Eclipse. Could you say me how to get SDK manager Support Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already downloaded Android support Repository .

To add support library to project, go to android sdk location `sdk\extras\android\support` , you can find all support libraries there .Add what ever library you need as a dependency

i guess you have to add V7 appCompact

Comment: I have this folder C:\Users\Carlota\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository. But I don't have more libraries

Comment: below m2repository there should be support folder

Comment: may be your sdk location is wrong, if you cant find that folder,You can still download support libraries online and add it to eclipse project

Comment: I work with Windows. I don't have other folder in android. Could you say me how to download support libraries online

Comment: check  inside /extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/    folder   see this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Is it mandatory to use gradle?. I read other questions and they use a .jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131695/discussion-between-user3712581-and-redman).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux. Try doing this in the terminal, it worked for me at some point in time. Don't know if it still works:

```
:~$ android list sdk -a --extended|less
```

This will list all the packages plus the `extra-androidm2-repository` because of the --extended option. After this you can the type:

```
android update sdk --no-ui -a --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
```

This will proceed to download the extra support repository, and place it in the $ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository/.If that does not work try downloading the zip file [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r33.zip). This is still not the end of it because you still have to find a way to use it and

**This is why you should move to Android studio**

1. The structure of android support repository changed to the .aar format. This means you cannot import the library as you would have with earlier support versions. You have to use maven plugin in eclipse to manage the libraries.
2. Maven central does not have the latest android support libraries, hence you have to use maven android connector.
   If you want to read more, on how to Mavenize your project and use maven for android libraries read [this](http://www.tikalk.com/devops/android-eclipse-maven/). I found it personally to be very hard compared to android studio where you just have to add a dependency in gradle. Good luck.